# Gerrit setup - how to register first user?

Tags: linux, git, gerrit

I am a newcomer to the gerrit.

I installed the latest gerrit 2.11.3 on
a fresh virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
using the below manual:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-gerrit-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server

#### Step1: Preliminary

```
ssh root@178.62.75.140
apt-get update && reboot
apt-get upgrade && reboot
apt-get install default-jre
apt-get install git
```

#### Step 2: Install the gerrit

```
wget https://gerrit.googlecode.com/files/gerrit-2.7-rc1.war
git config -f ~/gerrit_example/etc/gerrit.config gerrit.canonicalWebUrl
~/gerrit_example/bin/gerrit.sh restart
```

#### Step 3: Access gerrit through browser

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
```

Well, the above "xxx" marks should be replaced by the below IP address:

```
178 dot 62 dot 75 dot 140
```

Choose to use `Sign in with a Yahoo! ID` and the browser return `Server not found` :-( .

And BTW!! You are welcome to ssh this machine and do **whatever** you want to make gerrit work! **Any** modern gerrit version!!

```
IP: 178.62.75.140
User: root
Password: kostaz123
```

Thanks a bunch!
--- KostaZ

Comment: The instructions to which you've linked already have instructions for creating a new user (in the section titled, "Step Five—Create a New User").  Did this not work correctly?

Comment: Your gerrit is v2.7-rc1, or so it says in the interface

Comment: I did try "Step Five—Create a New User" with Yahoo OpenID. It fails with "Server not found" message.

Comment: I tried it with Gerrit v2.7-rc1 and with Gerrit v2.11.3. The result is the same. I miss something basic...

Comment: I intentionally replaced your ip address with xxx. The first person to register on gerrit is assigned admin rights. You don't want any of us to be that, I assumed

Comment: Anyway it works for me. I am redirected to yahoo login page

Comment: The redirection is ok. But when you press 'ok' there you get "Server not found".

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Yahoo needs to be able to reach gerrit

Comment: I **do want** for anyone to become the admin on my gerrit. This is the whole point of the real life test!! I specifically allocated clean virtual machine for this question. I mean this for **anyone** - just connect to this `http://178.62.75.140:8080` gerrit and do **anything** you want with to make it work!!